# Always show nearest tooltip

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chartist.js

In a ChartJS line chart I always want to show a tooltip of the nearest point in the data - no matter what y-coord the mouse in the chart has.

I can partially achieve this by increasing the `pointHitRadius` to a large value like 250.

But then not only the nearest point is activated, but also many others in the nearer surrounding.

Since only one tooltip is shown at once, the tooltip is right - but the many other "activated" points are disturbing. Are the a way to always show the nearest tooltip but not using `pointHitRadius`?

[image]

Comment: `'nearest'` is the default [interaction `mode`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html). Please check the [sample on interaction](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/interactions.html) if what you need cannot be achieved by setting some of those options. If not, and code is required, please provide your code, so we have something to start from.